# Why does python find the line 'ens' but not 'tun' when using `for line in open()`

Tags: python, interface

I have the following function I'm using to check whether an interface exists or not:

```
def status(interface):
    print("Checking VPN Status...")
    for line in open('/proc/net/dev'):
            if interface in line:
                proof = line.split(" ")[1].split()
                print(proof)
                return proof
```

Here is a copy of my /proc/net/dev file:

```
$ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
 ens33: 1480355767 23538625   13    1    0     0          0         0 752613935 44655037    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 548140418 2567168    0    0    0     0          0         0 548140418 2567168    0    0    0     0       0          0
  tun0:   17067       85     0    0    0     0          0         0   10819     114    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

If I call status('ens'), I get the correct output:

```
['ens33:]
```

But if I call status('tun'), which I fully expect to work, I get:

```
[]
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you have multiple spaces in the last line. Try using `split` without any arguments.

Comment: Try printing out `line.split(" ")` for each line.  Element [1] of that is going to be an empty string for any line starting with two or more spaces.

Comment: it *is* finding it, you are just returning the first item if you split on a single space, which in this case, is not the string you are interested in. Print `line` instead of `proof` and you'll see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tun0` line begins with two spaces, so `line.split(" ")` returns `['', '', 'tun0:', ... ]`, meaning element 1 is itself a blank space.

If you use just plain `split()`, it won't preserve the whitespace, and will just return `['tun0:']`.  (In this case you'd need to access element zero instead of element one.)